# Jquery refresh div

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, settimeout

I've got a certain php code in a div which gets data from mysql.I want this div to refresh every minute without refreshing the entire page.

Currently I'm using this, doesn't work well

```
<div id="abc">
<?php

?>
</div>

window.setTimeout('location.reload()', 60000);
```

Comment: You have to use Ajax.

Comment: ... or an iframe, which is not recommended.

Comment: @undefined actually an iframe is sometimes the only option when it has it's own stylesheets.

Answer (score 4):

The ideal way to do this is to use [jQuery.aja](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)x to retrieve data from your server, and then use JavaScript/jQuery within your `success` function to update your page.

You can still use `setTimeout` or equivalent to periodically issue AJAX requests.

Comment: The `setTimeout` should be called inside the `success` function to avoid stacking failed or unexpectedly long requests.

Answer (score 3):

As you want to refresh the div content every minute you need to look at [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) method and [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) of jQuery:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  $('#abc').load('PHPFile.php');
}, 1000);
```

and your PHP script mentioned in the url part of the load method must be capable to provide the result in HTML format which is going to be placed in the given div (id:abc)

Answer (score 1):

Have the PHP-code on another page (for example; loaddata.php) and have a jQuery timer executing a function which loads the page *loaddata.php*

**Loaddata.php**

```
<?php
    echo "Hello World!";    
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<div id="data"></div>

<script>
    $('#div').load("loaddata.php", function() {
        window.setInterval("loadData", 60000);
    });

    function loadData()
    {
        $('#div').load("loaddata.php");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
function refreshContent() {
    $.post(urlHere, { data here...}, success(data) {
        //...manipulate DOM here...
    }
}

setTimeout(refreshContent, 60000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Example of jQuery Ajax

**file1.php**

```
<?php
  echo 'PHP content e.g. from database based on submitted request - '.$_POST['my-value'];
?>
```

**file2.html**

```
<div class="content"></div>
<a href="#" class="reload-data"> Refresh div </a>

<script>
$(function(){
  $(".reload-data").click(function(){
    $.post("file1.php", {my-value: "something"}, function(data){
      $(".content").html(data);
    });
  });
});
setTimeout(function(){$(".reload-data").click();}, 60000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For these situations I sometimes use [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Example from documentation:

```
<div id="result"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function refreshDiv() {
    $('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container', function(){ /* callback code here */ });
}
setInterval(refreshDiv, 10000);
</script>
```

This does the following:

- Checks if the `#result` element is in the current page
- If it is, it makes a request to the `ajax/test.html` page
- Grabs the `#container` from the response, and dumps it into `#result`
- And it does this every 10 seconds

That's about it. One line of code, although not as efficient as a true ajax request, it does the job.